# Serializable control and Externilzable complete control

Tags: java, serialization

What is the difference between (readObject/writeObject in `Serializable`) and the `Externalizable` Interface?

I understood that both are used for controlling the serialization process. What I see in tutorials is `Externalizable` gives more complete control in the serialization process.

I did not get the excact difference between these as in which scenario (readObject/writeObject in `Serializable`) and `Externalizable` will be used?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, that using `Externalizable` you are not dependent on the default implementation, and you can define your own read/write methods. In `Serializable` the class just serialized as a whole.